# how to enable automatic login after waking up from suspend in Loki?

Tags: release-loki

In my setup, whenever I wake up from suspend, the login window comes up in another monitor that's in a different room. I can't seem to get the display manager to run the login window in my main display, so I thought of simply getting rid of its annoyance. Up to now I've been unsuccessful in doing so. I've tried editing /etc/default/acpi-support and commenting out the `LOCK_SCREEN` line, and also ran `gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.lockdown disable-lock-screen 'true'` and `gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.screensaver ubuntu-lock-on-suspend 'false'` , which were quoted as valid solutions to my problem (so the system would just autologin like it's supposed to after waking up from sleep or hibernate), but to no avail. I'm out of options at the moment. Is there something else I can do?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go into `System Settings > Security & Privacy > Locking` and disable both options. Also if you want to autologin every time you boot up your PC you have to enable the option inside `User Accounts`.

Comment: Thanks, that did it! I thought it was under screensaver or something related.